# Quotient of $S^1$ by dense subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory

I am trying to compute the quotients of the circle group $S^1$ by its various subgroups. So far, I have a rough classification of subgroups, namely that all finite subgroups of order $n$ are the $n$-th roots of unity $\Gamma_n$, and all other subgroups are dense in $S^1$.

For the case of finite subgroups, the group homomorphism sending $a \mapsto a^n$ gives an isomorphism between $S^1/\Gamma_n$ and $S^1$ by the first isomorphism theorem.

I am somewhat lost when it comes to a dense subgroup $H$; Is it even possible to determine the quotient $S^1/H$ knowing only that $H$ is a dense subgroup, or would one require a more specific classification of subgroups?
How could I proceed to better classify the subgroups, or compute the quotient?

Comment: I don't know about your question, but $Tor(S^1)$, the torsion part of $S^1$ is $\mathbb{Q/Z}$, in particular it's injective and so $S^1\simeq \mathbb{Q/Z}\times S^1/Tor(S^1)$; now $S^1/Tor(S^1)$ is divisible because $S^1$ is, and it's torsion free, therefore it is uniquely divisible and so a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Cardinality considerations show it has the same dimension as $\mathbb{R}$ and so is isomorphic to it. Therefore $S^1\simeq \mathbb{Q/Z\times R}$. The finite subgroups correspond to subgroups of $\mathbb{Q/Z}$, and the rest are dense. (1/2)

Comment: But then as you can see the subgroups are as complicated as those of $\mathbb{R}$ and those of $\mathbb{Q}$ and computing their quotients is just as hard as computing $\mathbb{R}/H$ and $\mathbb{Q}/H$ so I don't know if much can be said. (2/2)

Comment: Here's a side question.  As you know, given  a real number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha/2\pi$ is irrational, you get a dense subgroup  $H_\alpha=\{\exp (\sqrt{-1}n\alpha),\;n\in\mathbb{Z}\}\subset S^1$. Suppose I  give you a dense subset $H\subset S^1$  and I tell you  that $H=H_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$.  Can one determine $\alpha$ from this information alone? We know that $H_\alpha$ is infinite cyclic so the question is how can one determine its generators.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "compute" (since it's not a computational problem), nor "determine", but the possible quotients, up to group isomorphism are somewhat immediate, namely all divisible abelian groups of cardinal $\le \mathfrak{c}$. This yields the groups $\mathbf{Q}^{(\alpha_0)}\oplus\bigoplus_pC_{p^\infty}^{(\alpha_p)}$, where $p$ ranges among primes and $\alpha_i$ ranges over cardinals $\le \mathfrak{c}$, and $C_{p^\infty}\simeq\mathbf{Z}[1/p]/\mathbf{Z}$ is the Prüfer group.